# Add a header and footer to magento through XML update

Tags: magento

Is there any way to simply add the standard Magento header and footer to an "empty" layout by using the Layout Update XML?

I need this since I only have access to the CMS pages and not the source and want to have an empty column where I can try out inline designs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update PHP code for your header section. There is no such way to get data and simply add that in header or footer in Magento (CMS).

XML are used to import data only such as images, text, music etc.

If you have any concern, let us know anytime.

Thank You

Comment: Oh ok, just to make sure I asked it the correct way, I don't want to change anything in the actual header/footer I just want it added to the page? Like when I choose the "1 column" design. So that's not possible?

Comment: Yes its possible. You need to build different headers for example: Header1-template.php, Header2-template.php you can call them on specified way. If you have worked on Theme Options section building. You can get this done from graphics interface too. If you are beginner I suggest you to call php files directly using require or include functions. For reference you can get help from php.net official site for PHP